I have 4 monitors working on a Dell Inspiron 7786 & D6000 Dock and Ubuntu 23.1, but cannot see more than 2 monitors with Ubuntu 24. Fix?
EDITED: See end for 24.04LTS System Details:
I am changing my 23.1 expired support from a shared drive with windows 11 to a dedicated 1TB drive with 24.04 LTS
I changed the NVIDIA drivers v 535 when I installed 23.01 and 4 monitors are recognized and perform perfectly.
Now with 24.04 LTS, changing the drivers in any combination - 535, 540, 550 and I cannot get 24.04 LTS  to recognize more than two monitors running through the sudo commands.  I like the 24.04 LTS added features and LTS, but not having access to all my monitors is a deal breaker to upgrade from 23.01 which support has lapsed.
I thought the 4 monitor issue was resolved permanently with the 24.04 LTS build, as the new drivers are included and installed according to the "Software & Updates - Additional Drivers"
I do not see anyone successful getting more than TWO monitors to be seen.
Does anyone have the correct drivers and sudo keystrokes for the NVIDIA and INTEL that work with 24.04 LTS to get 4 monitors working again?
Did someone forget to grab the correct NVIDIA configurations in this latest build?
Here is what I have in 23.01 with 4 monitors working with NVIDIA Driver 535:
System Details Report

Report details

Date generated:                              2024-11-19 10:13:51

Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              Dell Inc. Inspiron 7786
Memory:                                      32.0 GiB
Processor:                                   Intel® Core™ i7-8565U × 8
Graphics:                                    Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (WHL GT2)
Graphics 1:                                  NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150]
Disk Capacity:                               1.0 TB

Software Information:

Firmware Version:                            1.16.0
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 23.10
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               Not Available
Windowing System:                            X11
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.5.0-14-generic

Here is the 24.04 LTS System Details 2 monitors working with NVIDIA Driver 550
System Details Report

Report details

Date generated:                              2024-11-20 16:19:44

Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              Dell Inc. Inspiron 7786
Memory:                                      32.0 GiB
Processor:                                   Intel® Core™ i7-8565U × 8
Graphics:                                    Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (WHL GT2)
Graphics 1:                                  NVIDIA GeForce MX150
Disk Capacity:                               1.0 TB

Software Information:

Firmware Version:                            1.16.0
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               46
Windowing System:                            X11
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.8.0-48-generic

TERMINAL sudo ...
*************-Inspiron-7786:~$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-550
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-driver-550 is already the newest version (550.120-0ubuntu0.24.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
Apologies, I am not an expert like some others.

This question is similar to: After Ubuntu 24.04 upgrade multiple displays not working. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Your details are rather unclear, except you're using an off-topic due to EOL release. Asking about upgrading an EOL release is on-topic, but you mention v24 where the 24th release was Ubuntu 16.04 LTS which is EOSS too; the latest release in October 2024 (24.10) is NOT a LTS as the older 2024-April release was (24.04). Being clear & specific with details matter; 24 is closest to Ubuntu Core 24 which is a headless server release, but no supported release of Ubuntu uses the EOL 6.5 kernel. For specific help, being specific with details is required.

So I went back into how I resolved my issue in 23.01 from my downloads resolving that 4 monitor issue. The question for 24.04 is asked for DisplayLink below.
Not getting 4 monitors to display on the Dell D6000 was actually NOT an NVIDIA driverproblem, but a DisplayLink problem because the problem lives in the Dell D6000 Dock driver evdi-dkms package.
I am working through the DisplayLink issues from the DisplayLink issue
How to install DisplayLink-Driver on Ubuntu 24.04.01 LTS?
and will post an update when I get around to running the updates on 24.04.
UPDATE:  DisplayLink drivers for 24.04.01 are here https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu
UPDATE 2:  Installed the DisplayLink 6.1 evdi-dkms package for 24.04.01, I now have all four monitors working perfectly again!
